# SYN ACK not getting received

Tags: http, ip, tcp

I am implementing a server and have an issue with the handshaking. When I get the arp request the response is given ok, then I get the SYN. I respond to the SYN with a SYN ACK but I don't get an ACK back.

The sequence numbers and ack's seem to be in order as well as the id's, the checksums add up aswell to. Any ideas why the SYN ACK is not getting recieved?

Arp Request:

```
0000   ff ff ff ff ff ff e0 3f 49 b7 8e 39 08 06 00 01
0010   08 00 06 04 00 01 e0 3f 49 b7 8e 39 c0 a8 00 01
0020   00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 a8 00 0c
```

Arp reply:

```
0000   ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 14 a5 76 19 3f 08 06 00 01
0010   08 00 06 04 00 02 00 14 a5 76 19 3f c0 a8 00 0c
0020   e0 3f 49 b7 8e 39 e0 3f 49 b7 00 00 00 00 00 00
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

SYN:

```
0000   00 14 a5 76 19 3f e0 3f 49 b7 8e 39 08 00 45 00
0010   00 34 1e d2 40 00 80 06 5a 94 c0 a8 00 01 c0 a8
0020   00 0c 13 79 00 50 95 01 61 8e 00 00 00 00 80 02
0030   20 00 c3 59 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01
0040   04 02
```

SYN ACK:

```
0000   e0 3f 49 b7 8e 39 00 14 a5 76 19 3f 08 00 45 00
0010   00 2c 1e d2 40 00 80 06 5a 9c c0 a8 00 0c c0 a8
0020   00 01 00 50 13 79 d6 a2 5f 1b 95 01 61 8f 60 12
0030   05 ee d0 e6 00 00 02 04 05 78 00 00
```

Comment: Have you tried get pcap with wireshark?

Comment: The packets above were captured using wireshark.

Comment: So why not show the wireshark decoded packets? Not fun to do decoding by hand, specially not if for free :-)

Comment: Still getting used to wire shark, I didn’t know there was such a function. As it turns out the length field was incorrect. When this was updated correct, the method worked fine. Wireshark is a very useful tool.